# Is there any way that adjusted R squared would be greater than R squared?

Tags: multiple-regression, r-squared

Is there any way that adjusted $R^2$ would be greater than $R^2$? Including cases of extreme values of n and p and negative values of $R^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it can't. Check out this [summary](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/multiple-regession-analysis-use-adjusted-r-squared-and-predicted-r-squared-to-include-the-correct-number-of-variables).

Edit: Just to flush out a bit more

The formula is $R^2_{adj} = 1 - \frac{(N-1)}{N-p-1}(1-R^2) $ where N = sample size, p = number of predictors, and $R^2$ is, well, $R^2$. So at best with an enormous number of samples and a small number of predictors, it can approach the original $R^2$ as $\frac{(N-1)}{N-p-1}$ approaches 1.

Comment: The argument is correct--but it's not quite general enough to address the situation implied by the question.  The suggestion that $R^2$ could be negative hints that a regression through the origin is contemplated, in which case the correct formula for adjusted $R^2$ is slightly different than the one given here.  The conclusion remains true--in fact, the adjustment is even greater in that case--but it might be worth pointing out that the *absolute value* of the adjusted $R^2$ easily could exceed that of $R^2$ (fwiw). In the most extreme cases $R^2=0$ whereas the adjusted value is $-1$.